# Batch process ffmpeg?

Tags: bash, ffmpeg, command-line

Given an AVI encapsulated video with WMA2 audio and MP4 video how do I pass-through the video, convert the audio to MP3; then re-encapsulate the entire file into an AVI?

```sh
ffmpeg -i "foo bar.avi" -acodec libmp3lame "Converted\foo bar.avi"
```

**Now how do I do that same command for every `.avi` file in this directory?**

(need a solution using bash or Windows CLI [`for`?])

Comment: Are you observing any particular failure on running the command given in the question?

Comment: Nope; I am not.

Comment: So this command is successful & you see the output file generated as you want?

Comment: By the way, if you want to pass through video "AS-IS", then add `-vcodec copy` in the ffmpeg command line. It will save video conversion time + retain the same quality in video.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Python solution

```py
from sh import ffmpeg
from os import listdir
from os.path import split
from sys import argv

[ffmpeg("-i '{0}' -acodec libmp3lame 'Converted\{0}'".format(_file))
 for _file in sum([listdir(split(arg)[0]) for arg in argv], [])]
```

Answer (score 4):

Do this not simply work?

```
for file in *.avi;do ffmpeg -i "$file" -acodec libmp3lame "Converted\\$file";done
```

**Edit**:

There seem to by a backslash problem...

Try this:

```
for file in *.avi;do ffmpeg -i "$file" -acodec libmp3lame 'Converted\\'"$file";done
```

or this:

```
for file in *.avi;do ffmpeg -i "$file" -acodec libmp3lame 'Converted\'"$file";done
```

Comment: @imp25 Maybe do you need to escape the backslash: ` \\ ` instead of ` \ `

Comment: Nope, now getting same error (the final error I mentioned) on both `//` and `\\\`

Comment: Well, there is a *conflict* as Windows use ` \ ` for path and shell use ` \ ` for escape. Unfortunely ` \$var ` could be used to print effectively `$var`. So try the editer version, maybe.

Comment: The first version should work in Bash.

Answer (score 1):

In `bash` the following will do what you want if your run it in the directory which has the `.avi` files:

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in *.avi; do
    ffmpeg -i "$file" -c:a libmp3lame "Converted\\$file";
done;
```

Comment: I was first ;-)

Comment: Thanks, but neither worked. I am using Cygwin bash if that makes a difference.

Comment: Was there any error message? How did it not work?

Comment: `[NULL @ 03890340] Unable to find a suitable output format for 'Converted$file' Converted$file: Invalid argument` then after changing `\\` to `/` got this error: `Converted/my filename here.avi: No such file or directory`. It was able to open the file (stream info for the input is above this text).

Comment: What happens when you use a full path, and using cygwin's path format (which follows unix's /path/to/foo format)? You can convert a windows path into a cygwin path using `cygpath`; see http://stackoverflow.com/a/4337071/1608708.

Answer (score 0):

After a trial & error conversation with the commands involved I found that this works in a bash shell

```
for i in *.ts; do ffmpeg -i "$i" -threads 6 -f mpegts -vcodec libx264 -preset slow -bufsize 8000 -async 48000 -acodec ac3 -ab 384k -n subdir/"${i%}"; done
```

this makes a high quality compressed version of input .ts files with the same name but in a subdir. I'm guessing it wont write a subdir if it doesn't exist so you would have to specify one that does in substitution for what I'm calling "subdir". Also I used -n to keep it from overwriting files I individually rendered before I discovered the proper syntax for this batch process.(I have a 6 core processor so "-threads" should be adjusted as well to your hardware)